# Does astyanax support autodiscovery mode for local nodes only?

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax, netflix

I have recently started using `Cassandra` in our `Production environment`. We have a `24 node cluster` with `replication factor of 4`. Meaning `2 copies` will be there in `each datacenter`. So that means we have a single cross colo cluster with `24 nodes` which means `12 nodes in SLC colo` and `12 nodes in PHX colo`.

I am using `Astyanax client` to write the data in `Cassandra database`. Now I am trying to figure out is there any way `Astyanax client` will be able to figure out all the `nodes in the PHX colo or SLC colo` and not all of the nodes?

In my `setSeeds` method I will be passing the nodes related to only `one datacenter`. It will be either SLC or PHX. So if you take a look into my below code, I have specified 2 nodes in my `setSeeds method` and all those nodes belongs to `PHX colo`. Now I am trying to have auto discovery mode enabled but only for that particular colo. So in my case it should be able to detect 12 nodes for PHX colo not all the 24 nodes.

Below is my code in which I am using `ConnectionPoolType` as `TOKEN_AWARE` which by default uses `NodeDiscoveryType` as `RING_DESCRIBE` and that will show me all the `24 nodes` corresponding to both the `colos/datacenter` and that's what I don't want. I need to have all the nodes corresponding to each colo/datacenter

**Any idea how can I achieve this scenario using Astyanax client? Is this possible?**

```
private CassandraAstyanaxConnection() {

    context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster(ModelConstants.CLUSTER)
    .forKeyspace(ModelConstants.KEYSPACE)
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(40)
        .setSeeds("cdb03.vip.phx.host.com:9160,cdb04.vip.phx.host.com:9160")
    )
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
        .setTargetCassandraVersion("1.2")
        .setConnectionPoolType(ConnectionPoolType.TOKEN_AWARE))
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

    context.start();
    keyspace = context.getEntity();

    emp_cf = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(
        ModelConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY, 
        StringSerializer.get(), 
        StringSerializer.get());
}
```

**In short- does astynanx support autodiscovery for local nodes only?**

Why I am asking this is because of RING_DESCRIBE, it will give me all the nodes from both the colo. So suppose if I am running my program from PHX colo then it might possibily go to SLC colo to get the data and because of the reason I am seeing very bad write performance as the ping time between PHX and SLC is 15-20 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NodeDiscoveryType RING_DESCRIBE (or TOKEN_AWARE with no HostSupplier) Astyanax will discover all nodes, but you should also use setLocalDatacenter.  When setting up your AstyanaxContext using ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl use setLocalDatacenter with the desired DC. That will ensure that hosts from the other dc's are not in the connection pool and that your requests are local.

```
.withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(40)
        .setLocalDatacenter("DC1")
        .setSeeds("127.0.0.1:9160")
    )
```

Again, my understanding is that NodeDiscoveryType of TOKEN_AWARE (with no HostSupplier set) or RING_DESCRIBE will both result in the RingDescribeHostSupplier being used within Astyanax.  So, Astyanax will "know" about all of the nodes, but the connection pool will be limited (via setLocalDatacenter) to the DC specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `NodeDiscoveryType.TOKEN_AWARE`, as from the astyanax documentation it can be said that it was desgined for multi-region ring describe problem where ring describe return nodes from other regions or datacenters

Comment: I have already tried this but it always gives me all the nodes across all the data centers.